# SQL Server 2012 intellisense does not work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having problems with SQL server intellisense. It does not work for me at all. I did follow some of the troubleshooting steps [Mentioned here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/) but with no luck. And the similar installation does work for some of my colleagues.

Has anybody run into that and is there anything else I can do to make it work?

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion'); -> 11.0.6518.0

SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition'); -> Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
```

Comment: What version of Management Studio are you using?

Comment: That is 11.0.2100.60

Comment: Are you testing on a remote server? Does it work on a local database?

Comment: It is a remote server, and I haven't tried on the local database yet. I can try that but what makes it weird is some people are able to use this with the same installation and the same remote server.

Comment: Forget the SSMS, use ApexComplete. It's free and better than every thing. it may support remote server or if not, they are going to add that. http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx

Comment: Open SSMS  as 'Run as Administrator' and see if it works.

Comment: @SravanKumar That did not help either